# C: If statement not working

Tags: c, if-statement, divide-by-zero

```
if (num2 != 0)
    printf("\nInput 3 / Input 2 (int)    %12d", divide);
else if (num2 == 0)
    printf("\nInput 3 / Input 2 (int)    DIV/0");


if (flt4 != 0)
    printf("\nInput 2 / Input 1 (double) %16.3f", divide2);
else if (flt4 == 0)
    printf("\nInput 2 / Input 1 (double)    DIV/0");
```

When I set num2 or flt4 equal to 0 the program crashes. Otherwise it works perfectly fine. I was looking over the reading about if/else statements and I believe my formatting is correct, but there is obviously an error.

Thanks.

EDIT:

The code where i define divide is:

```
void calculate (int num1, int num2, int num3, float flt4,int* sum,int* mult,
            int* mod,int* divide,double* mult2,double* divide2)
{

*sum = num1 + flt4;
*mult = num1 * num3;
*mod = (num1/10)%10;
*divide= num3 / num2;
*mult2= num1 * flt4;
*divide2= (double)num2 / num1;
return;
}
```

My question then is, how do I structure this program so if it divides by zero I can display that in the print function.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. It has to crash in different place than what you pasted. BTW - you do not need to specify the other 'if' after 'else' for it is already implied by the previous if.

Comment: Given that `divide` is a variable and not a function called in-place, I'd say you're **always** performing the division, and only after having done that (and having stored the result in the `divide` variable) you check for the denominator being non-zero. Of course if it is (would be) zero, then your program has already crashed.

Comment: Show the code where you define `divide`. Does it look like `divide = something / num2`? If so, then you're dividing by 0, which is invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you are dividing by zero. The `divide` variable is set before the 'if' and you perform that operation anyway. Put that inside the first 'if', so it will divide by the `num2` iff `num2` is different than zero.

Edit:
It should look like that:

```
if (num2 != 0) {
    divide = something / num2;
    printf("\nInput 3 / Input 2 (int)    %12d", divide);
}
```

Comment: I would do that but the teacher specified that I must do all calculations in a separate calculation function. So is the only solution is to make another variable in the calculation function that is a boolean for if it is equal to zero or not?

Comment: So use the `calculate` function after you check if the values are correct. You shouldn't perform `*divide= num3 / num2;` before you check the variables.